# TweenMax instance handling

Tags: javascript, gsap

Do TweenMax instances need to be cleared/unset/killed manually or is it done automatically? Here's the following code I'm using to add effect to a piece of text on screen:

```
TweenMax.to($('#score'), 0.25, { fontSize: '56px', onComplete: myFunction });

function myFunction(){
    TweenMax.to($('#score'), 0.125, { fontSize: '28px' });
}
```

This piece of code runs a lot and I'm afraid over time some garbage would pile up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and use the [kill()](http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/core/Animation.html#kill%28%29) method:

Also you can store your reference to the tween in a variable:

[Check out this Example](http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/ohvga/)

```
var myTween = TweenMax.to($('#score'), 0.25, { fontSize: '56px', onComplete: myFunction });

function myFunction(){
   myTween.kill();
   myTween = TweenMax.to($('#score'), 0.125, { fontSize: '28px' });
}
```

For more info checkout the GreenSock [TweenMax Docs](http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/TweenMax.html).